# Application of Stone-Weierstrass (Proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, weierstrass-approximation

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Assume $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)e^{-nt}dt=0$ whenever $n$ is a non-negative integer. Does it follow $f$ is identically $0$? Does the answer change if $-nt$ is replaced by $+nt$? $2nt?$

My work: Consider the sub-algebra of $C[0,1]$ generated by $e^{-nt}$. Let $P_n(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+⋯+a_1x+a_0$. Consider $A=\{P_n(e^{-t})∣n=0,1,2,3…\}$. It's not difficult to see that $A$ is a sub-algebra of $C[0,1]$ since $A$ is closed under multiplication & addition.

Moreover, $A$ vanishes at no point in $[0,1]$ since $e^{-t} \neq 0 $ for all $t$ and the same choice of element in $A$ proves that $A$ separates point in $[0,1].$

Now, the uniform closure of $A$ consists of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Since $f\in{C[0,1]}$, there exists $P_n(e^{-t})$ s.t $P_n(e^{-t})\rightarrow f(t)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. So, $P_n(e^{-t})f(t)\rightarrow f(t)^2$ uniformly. Therefore,
$$\int_{0}^{1}P_n(e^{-t})f(t)\,\mathrm dt \rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}f(t)^2\,\mathrm dt\text{ as }n\rightarrow \infty$$
But, $\int_{0}^{1}P_n(e^{-t})f(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$ for all $n$. Hence, $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)^2\,\mathrm dt=0$. By continuity, we obtain $f≡0$.

The result holds true even if we replace $-nt$ by $+nt$. But, I wonder if this is true for all even exponents & similarly for odd exponents?

Is my approach to this problem correct?

Comment: what's the closed subalgebra generated by all $e^{2nt}$?

Comment: {$P_n(e^{2t})|n=0,1,2,3,...$}?. This should be an algebra as well right.I guess it's not the case for odd exponents ($2n+1$)?

Comment: If you know $\int_0^1 f(t)e^{2nt}\,dt=0$ for all $n$ entails $f=0$, what does that tell you if you know $\int_0^1 f(t)e^{(2n+1)t}\,dt=0$ for all $n$?

Comment: This holds true for odd exponents too?. (since we can decompose the integral into one with even exponents & $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)e^{t} dt$.

Comment: But, {$P_{2n+1}(e^{t})|n=0,1,2,3,...$} is not an algebra since it's not closed under multiplication.

Comment: If you know “$\int_0^1 f(t)e^{2nt}\,dt=0$ for all $n$ entails $f\equiv 0$”, then $\int_0^1 f(t)e^{(2n+1)t}\,dt=0$ for all $n$ entails $f(t)e^t=0$ i.e. $f=0$.